# How to access HTML file Document created through XMLHTTP request

Tags: vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I have got a `responseText` from an XMLHTTP request:

```
Set XMLHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
XMLHttp.Open "GET", urlPiece, False
XMLHttp.send
```

that I store in an HTML file created in memory:

```
Set htmlResponse = CreateObject("htmlfile")
htmlResponse.body.innerHTML = XMLHttp.responseText
```

If I look at the object `htmlResponse` on the debugger, I see the structure of a normal HTML file. However, when I try to get the document, I don't succeed:

```
Set doc = htmlResponse.document '<-- Invalid method or property
```

What am I doing wrong? Below my full code in case you want to test on real sample:

```
Sub getPrice()

    Dim urlPiece As String: urlPiece = "https://fr.finance.yahoo.com/q?s="
    Dim htmlResponse As Object
    Dim XMLHttp As Object

    Set htmlResponse = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    ccyPair = "XAUUSD"
    urlPiece = urlPiece & ccyPair & "=X"
    Set XMLHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    XMLHttp.Open "GET", urlPiece, False
    XMLHttp.send
    htmlResponse.body.innerHTML = XMLHttp.responseText
    Set doc = htmlResponse.document '<-- error here 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the mistake myself. 
Differently than JavaScript, the `document` is defined in the `body` of the `HTMLfile` and is not itself an attribute of the object. 
Hence:

```
Set doc = htmlResponse.document
```

should rather be

```
Set doc = htmlResponse.body.document
```